# Why isn't view available?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Why do I get:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

while switching to the next scene and back?

```
// Main Menu Scene

class MainMenuScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

//        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: "switchScene", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        println("loaded MainMenuScene")
    }

     override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {

            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        }
    }

    func switchScene() {

        println("switching to GameScene")
        var game = GameScene(size: CGSizeMake(2048, 1536))
        game.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        if self.view == nil {
            println("no self.view")
        } else {
        self.view!.presentScene(game)
        }
    }
}

// Game Scene

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

//        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: "switchScene", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {

            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        }
    }

    func switchScene() {

// make var a member variable or this won't work
timer.invalidate()
        var menu = MainMenuScene(size: CGSizeMake(2048, 1536))
        menu.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        self.view!.presentScene(menu)
    }
}
```

First,  change timer variable to a member.
Second, invalidate the timer.

Everything runs as expected.

Comment: why are you using a repeating timer if you are switching out of the view when the timer ticks? And its better to use SKActions to time things in SpriteKit.

Comment: Added solution in original post.

Answer (score 1):

From the `SKScene` docs:

> To present a scene, you call the `presentScene:` method or `presentScene:transition:` method on the SKView class. If the scene is not currently presented, this property holds `nil`.

`view` is `nil` because the your `GameScene` (`self`) is not currently presented when this code runs. Your app crashes because you are force-unwrapping something that's `nil`.

Comment: Isn't the view presented when viewDidLoad is triggered? Where would I put this code? Strange, this did work another time as I was able to switch screens every 2 seconds.

Comment: Also why do I have 2 negative comments next to my question (post). Does this mean I had a stupid question, or that I should have know the answer?

Comment: I'm not sure why your question is downvoted - maybe because it's not specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Aaron was right. If you put remove the timer, or don't add enough time, then the view will be nil. In this instance, with the timer, by time the timer trigged, view did have a view initially.

What I was forgetting to do was invalidate() my timer before presenting the new SKScene. This kept the timer running, and when it triggers, view! is really nil because the object was removed.

Comment: I don't think that makes my answer wrong. `view` is `nil` when you force-unwrapped it, which is what I said.

Comment: True, which is why I voted your question the correct answer. I will make that clearer though.